# How do I flex horizontally within a column layout? Currently only half the width of the screen

Tags: react-native, flexbox

How do I flex horizontally within a column layout? Currently only half the width of the screen

Here's the current render code:

```
render() {
    const {handle_data} = this.state
    if (handle_data.length) {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          {
            handle_data.map(pack => {
              console.log('this.cleanDataForFlatlist(pack): ', this.cleanDataForFlatlist(pack))
              return (
                <View style={styles.pack}>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'},{fontSize: 24}}>{pack[0].pack_name}</Text>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'},{fontSize: 16}}>{pack[0].pack_description}</Text>
                  <View style={styles.pack}>
                    <FlatList
                      data={this.cleanDataForFlatlist(pack)}
                      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                      renderItem={this._renderHandle}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              )
            })
          }
        </ScrollView>
      );
    } else {
      return null
    }

  }
```

[Here's what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRfx3.png)

Comment: Could you show you render code?

Comment: @Lenoarod added, thanks for looking into it! By the way, it made me remove the styles code, but I'll throw it here: const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
  },
  pack: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    marginVertical: 5,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  handles: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  }

Comment: Also, I'm actually trying to (ultimately) show two of the "handles" per row, if that's something you have expertise on as well. Probably would be useful to see how to do do 1 per row and 2 per row, so I can see what looks better. No pressure to help on this part, though :)

Comment: I post an answer, you can try it

Comment: Here is my render about an item, if that helps       _renderHandle = ({item}) => {
    console.log('item in _renderHandle: ', item)
    return (<Card
      //change this to Button and see what happens!
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HandleDetails', {
                id: item.id,
                image_url: item.image_url,
                title: item.title,
                short_desc: item.short_desc
              })}
      image={item.image_url}
      title={item.title}
      description={item.short_desc}
    />)
  };

Comment: FlatList is used to render array, so you do not use it in the array map. then make the card(Button suggest TouchOpacity) width "100%"

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your code about an item, so I show an example code. your problem is mainly the item render.

```
 // the soruceData is the data souce,in other words, your handle_data
<View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'transparent'}} >
            <FlatList
            data={this.state.sourceData}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
</View>

//the render item method, I suggest you put the item into a pure component
 _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'column',width:'92%'}>
            id={item.id} // the every item should hava a unique id or key
            <ImageView source={{uri:"image url"}} style={{width:,height:}}/>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{fontSize: 18,
             color: '#353535',}}>"content"</Text>
        />
    );
  };
```

you set layout width or height should use flex or percent. in this case, your UI is flexible.

At the same time, I suggest you read [felx layout guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

In the end, I suggest you remove the scroll view, move views which algin above the flatList into the flatList ListHeaderComponent. it can avoid the scroll conflict.